# Behaviour of LIMIT in Mariadb subquery

Tags: sql, mariadb, greatest-n-per-group

Here is my problem.

I'm not very good in SQL queries so I hope to get some insight into the different behaviours of the LIMIT clause. I have two queries. Lets say my table has 3 columns, `name`, `date`, and `date_modified`. I modify the table every hour and keep a revision of it using the `date_modified` column. I'm trying to get the last record (most recently modified) for the date modified for a particular date `2017-12-12`.

```
SELECT * from 
   (SELECT * from table where name in ('name1','name2','name3') 
    and date in ('2017-12-12') order by date_modified desc)
    as tmp_table group by name

SELECT * from 
   (SELECT * from table where name in ('name1','name2','name3') 
    and date in ('2017-12-12') order by date_modified desc LIMIT 100)
    as tmp_table group by name
```

The first one returns a table where the date modified is the earliest record for the day. The second one is the one I want, which returns the data with the latest modification. If I have a larger table where `name3` is the 101st record the query wont work properly. So hardcoding the LIMIT is both not viable and a bad practice.

Why is there a difference? Does order by not work in a subquery?

*I am just adding additional information as I think of a solution myself.

Adding on : The subqueries above have the same behaviour; i.e. the data is sorted in descending order according to the date modified.

Both `date_modified` and `date` are in datetime format.

Comment: Have a look at the stuff returned in your inner query. Does it behave like expected in the case where `name3` is the 101st record?

Comment: yes the inner query sorts the table correctly by date_modified. Im sorry theres a typo in the code. I just fixed it. I hope its clearer now

Comment: `SELECT * GROUP BY` is invalid SQL. What values do you expect to get for the columns not present in the `GROUP BY` clause? They are indeterminate.

Comment: You've tagged two different DBMS. Are you using MySQL or MariaSQL? They are kin, but they are still different from each other.

Comment: My bad. I'm using mariadb

Comment: On a sidenote: From your description it seems that `date_modified` is always `date` plus a time. Then you shouldn't store `date`, for that would be redundant. (But `date` could be  a computed column based on `date_modified` of course.)

Comment: This is  a "groupwise-max" problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A table is an unordered set of data. The same holds true for a derived table, i.e. a subquery.

**First query**

You select certain records from the table and order them. The DBMS is free to completely ignore this `ORDER BY` clause, because you only use the data as a subquery.

Then you group by name. Now we must distinguish two cases:

1. `name` + `date` is unique in the table. Then you return exactly the rows you found. The `GROUP BY` clause would be superfluous.
2. `name` + `date` is not unique in the table. But you `select *`. This is invalid SQL, because you don't tell the DBMS which values to pick in case you have multiple rows for one name and date. If MariaDB let's this slip, it's a flaw in the DBMS.

From your description it seems the second case applies. Your query is invalid.

**Second query**

You select certain records from the table and order them in order to apply the `LIMIT` clause. This limits the results but again the DBMS is free to output the rows in whatever order, as you use the data as a subquery. As you order by `date_modified` you may discard some names from the results (e.g. the last hundred records where all name1 and name2, then you dismiss name3 of course.

As to `GROUP BY name`: what I said in regards to the first query applies here, too. That you limit the data to 100 rows makes no difference.

Comment: Thanks. This answered my question. For my query, would it work if i create a temporary table, then select * from it? So it would be something like `select * from (create temporary table tmp(...))`

Comment: No. You must find a way to get the last entry per name. But you haven't found such way yet. I have shown the typical approach in my other answer. Another would be `select ... where (name, date_modified) in (select name, max(max_date_modified) from ... group by name)`.

Comment: Okay. One last question; so my query 2 gets the result but query 1 doesnt. And this is not due to the limit clause? Per what you said the DBMS arranges the output in whatever order and the "correct" order I got is by "chance" and the query is not reliable ya?

Comment: With your queries everything is left to chance. You should not even think about which one does something better than the other. They are invalid. Both. A better DBMS would have rejected them.

Answer (score 0):

*This is not really an answer to your question. See my other answer for a description what's wrong with your queries and your assumptions about their behavior.*

---

I guess what you want is this, the latest entry per name on December 12, 2017:

```
select *
from
(
  select 
    t.*, 
    max(date_modified) over (partition by name) as max_date_modified
  from t
  where name in ('name1', 'name2', 'name3') 
  and date in (date '2017-12-12')
) numbered
where date_modified = max_date_modified
order by name;
```

**UPDATE:** It seems MariaDB doesn't support `MAX OVER` yet (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/aggregate-functions-as-window-functions/). So use `ROW_NUMBER` instead:

```
select *
from
(
  select 
    t.*, 
    row_number() over (partition by Name order by date_modified desc) as rn
  from t
  where name in ('name1', 'name2', 'name3') 
  and date in (date '2017-12-12')
) numbered
where rn = 1
order by name;
```